# failing to send email with php

Tags: php, email

```
             $subject = "QA details were obtained";
                 $body = "
         email Info
         ";
        $headers = implode("\r\n", array(
          "MIME-Version: 1.0",
          "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1255",
          "From: mail@example.com"
        ));




                 if (mail($customer_email, $subject, $body,$headers)) {
                  echo "<p>Message successfully sent!</p>";


                 }
```

Basically, the email is being printed as successfully sent.. But in my email I dont get any email..

ps. I send email to myself so the variables are:

```
$customer_email = [my-email-address]
```

Comment: Is mail configured on the machine? Did you check your mail server's logs and this machine's mail logs?

Comment: how do i do that/? I am using yahoo.  I have yahoos mail. I obtain no messages..

Comment: have you check your mail in spam box?

Comment: By "your mail server" I mean the mail server your server is using to send mail, not the one you are using to receive mail. Also, I hope you didn't test with a fake source address, that will likely cause the mail server to reject your mail. (And it will mean you won't get the bounces, making troubleshooting extra hard.)

Comment: Try also to capture what's inside every var you use in the mail() function. Maybe, with an echo() function, you can see what's happenning. At least you will assure you the vars are correct.

Comment: what's under the [mail function] directive in your php.ini file?

Comment: What MTA are you using ? Sendmail ? Exim ? are they installed properly ?

Comment: How long have you not been receiving the mail? Especially on shared hosts, the mail may get stuck in a queue for a bit before it is sent.

Comment: elvenbyte. Thats what I did. Everything is set correctly.  I dont know about any of the other question

Answer (score 1):

Headers need to be seperated by CRLF (Carriage return & Line feed):

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1255\r\n";
$headers .= "From: mail@example.com\r\n";
```

or (easier to read)

```
$headers = implode("\r\n", array(
  "MIME-Version: 1.0",
  "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1255",
  "From: mail@example.com"
));
```

Otherwise, all headers will be interpreted as a single invalid header and may result in the mail not being sent.

Answer (score -1):

You should use quoted marks:

```
$customer_email = "makovetskiyd@yahoo.com";
```

Comment: I don't think so, in the first message, before editing the question, you had the $customer_email = makovetskiyd@yahoo.com, and that's wrong. You'll never send a mail, with the mail() function, if you have your mail address that way. Perhaps it isn't the perfect answer, but I don't think it is for a minus, but I can't do anything about it, so do what you want.